# Textboxes/form items are being cut off when user has the display set to Medium (125%)

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I have a **Windows Form** application written in VB.net. My users are telling me that when they go to **Control Panel > Display** and set their “size of text” to Medium (125%), TextBoxes and DropDown boxes on the Form are getting cut off. I have set the **AutoScaleMode** on the Form to DPI but that is not helping. Any Ideas?

Comment: Is there enough space for the bigger text?
If not, setting Autoscalemode will probably not help

Comment: @markschultheiss WTF? what in the world has `the browser` (whatever that means) have to do with a `WinForms` application??

Comment: @Christian Sauer how can I add more space?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of different approaches you can take:

1. Change the AutoScaleMode setting on all your forms and user controls to 'None' and just ensure that your labels etc. are long enough to handle the text of your UI in the most common DPI settings.  e.g., test for various DPI - if it works for 100%, 125%, & 150% you'll be in pretty good shape.
2. Switch to WPF (much easier said than done).
3. Try to get it working with AutoScaleMode set to DPI - this is very hard to do - if you research this you'll find that it is not trivial to get this working right.

Comment: +1 for `Switch to WPF`. That's the only hope for any winforms developers out there. By the way, it's probably easier (and faster) to do an entire application in WPF from scratch that trying to get anything useful out of winforms.

Comment: The problem is it is a very large application (that was converted from an old vb6 application) we have over 100 forms and switching to WPF (unless there is an automated way that I don't know) would be very difficult

Comment: @user889829 sorry but my point still stands.. Its probably easier and faster to migrate the 100+ forms to WPF (AND MVVM) than trying to hack something useful out of winforms.

Comment: At this point in time you really have to target what is coming after WPF, not WPF.  Unfortunately, by the time that *that* is stable, it will be on the way out too.  So currently you have to choose between stability and being current.

Comment: @davedoknjas you're right. Microsoft is pushing WinRT and all that stuff ultimately and it seems like WPF is being left behind. Still... the majority of concepts and capabilities in WPF is shared in all XAML-based technologies (WinRT / SL / WPF). At this point, anything is better than winforms. It's not a matter of being current, it's a matter of using a UI framework that can actually produce something useful. winforms cannot. (again, without resorting to an endless train of HACKS and workarounds to fix the bugs these hacks produce)

Comment: WinForms is kind of boring, but I think it works overall - you just have to know what Microsoft didn't get around to get working right (like AutoScaleMode).